# JavaScript Alert if two dates are not far enough apart

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to write a function that finds the difference in two dates, and if the two dates are not 20 days or more apart an error message appears after the user clicks out of the form field. The code below is supposed to do this. However, seeing as I am really new to JavaScript I would greatly appreciate some help and/or advice as how to fix my problem.
`

```
<html>
<head><title>Form test page</title></head>



<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="OnbordingInStyle.css">
<script>

function dateerror() {
    var c = 21;
    var x = date ();
    var y = document.getElementById('expected_start_date').value == "";
    if ( x + c - y <= 0) {
        datecrossover += "Attention this date is less than three weeks away, please be ready to expect delays with equipment for new employees \n";
        }
    if (datecrossover !="") {
        alert(datecrossover);
        return false;
        }
}
</script>

<form method="post" action="Test.php" onsubmit="return dateerror()">

<table>

<tr>
    <td>
    <label for="expectedstartdate">Expected Start Date</label>
    </td>
    <td><div class="required">
    <input type="date" name="expected_start_date" id="expected_start_date" size="15" maxlength="10" />*</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="date_completed" id="date_completed" />
                <script>
                    document.getElementById('date_completed').value = Date();
                </script>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" />
    </td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: What is the problem? Can you post the output it is giving you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you paste this into a new .html file - it should work :)

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"  />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script> 

<br><br><center>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nowdate" id="datepicker" value="07/01/2014">
    <input type="text" name="wantdate" id="datepicker2" value="07/31/2014">

    <input type="submit" name="submitJS" id="submitJS" value="Submit"  onclick="return ajaxSubmit();">
</form>
<script>
        function parseDate(str) {
            var mdy = str.split('/')
            return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
        }

        function daydiff(first, second) {
            return (second-first)/(1000*60*60*24);
        }

            function ajaxSubmit() { 

                    var date1 = $('#datepicker').val();
                    var date2 = $('#datepicker2').val();
                        //alert(date1 + " " + date2);
                        datediff = daydiff(parseDate($('#datepicker').val()), parseDate($('#datepicker2').val()));

                if(datediff != 21) { alert("These dates are not 21 days apart"); }
                return false;
            }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
var y = document.getElementById('expected_start_date').value == "";
```

looks suspicious to me. It is setting y to 1 or 0 depending on whether the expected start date is set, but it seems from your question that what you really wanted was

```
var y = document.getElementById('expected_start_date').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the date as a Date object. For example,

var x = new Date(Date.now());

That would set up a date with the current date and time. I'd recommend looking up the JavaScript reference at developer.Mozilla.com to learn more.